# BeamDeflection Plot

Tags: python, plot

I'm having trouble with my script not showing a plot. 
The plot must show the deflection of the beam as a function of the x-coordinate of the entire beam. I don't know if I can make the statements: "x[i]>a[v]" if x is not given...

```
import numpy as np  #Imports NumPy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def beamPlot(beamLength, loadPositions, loadForces, beamSupport):

    l=beamLength      #Scalar
    a=loadPositions   #Vector
    W=loadForces      #Vector
    x=np.array(range(0,l))

    E=200*10**9      #Constant [N/m^2]
    I=0.001          #Constant [m^4]


#Makes an empty vector with the same size as x
    y=np.empty_like(x)

    for i in range(np.size(x)):  #Continues as long as the vector x
        for v in range(np.size(a)):

            if a[v]==[ ] and W[v]==[ ]:
                return np.zeros(np.size(x))

            elif beamSupport=="both" and x[i]<a[v]:
                 y[i]=np.sum(((W[v]*(l-a[v])*x[i])/(6*E*I*l))*(l**2-x[i]**2-(l-a[v])**2))
            elif beamSupport=="both" and x[i]>=a[v]:   
                 y[i]=np.sum(W[v]*a[v]*(l-x[i])/(6*E*I*l)*(l**2-(l-x[i])**2-a[v]**2))                         
            elif beamSupport=="cantilever" and x[i]<a[v]:
                 y[i]=np.sum((W[v]*x[i]**2)/(6*E*I)*(3*a[v]-x[i]))
            elif beamSupport=="cantilever" and x[i]>=a[v]:
                 y[i]=np.sum((W[v]*a[v]**2)/(6*E*I)*(3*x[i]-a[v]))

        deflection=y 


    plt.ylim([0,10000])
    plt.xlim([0,l])
    plt.title("Beam deflection")
    plt.plot(x, deflection)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I've added an answer, but had to assume values for how you call the function. If my answer doesn't help, please add to your example the values you are using to call `beamPlot()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array `x` is created with a list of integers from `range(0,l)`, which means that the elements in the array are of type `int`. You create the `y` array using `np.epty_like()` which means that it also has elements of type `int`. Unless you are using huge values for the loads, the float values created by your calculations get rounded to `0` when converted to int, so the plot is a flat line at y=0.

You can fix this by specifying that `y` should contain float values when it is created by adding `dtype=float` to:

```
    y=np.empty_like(x, dtype=float)
```

You should also remove the `plt.ylim(0,10000)` and instead let matplotlib autoscale your y-axis, since the displacements are probably not going to be this large for any reasonable values of loads (given your stiffness)