# Python - solving Bernoulli's beam equation with scipy

Tags: python, scipy

The process of answering the question has already started in the question on the link bellow, but that topic was specifically about integrating a function, which was answered. So I added a new question.

[Python - Integrating a function and plotting results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64986667/python-integrating-a-function-and-plotting-results)

THE PROBLEM: how to solve a [beam equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Bernoulli_beam_theory) y''(x) = M(x) / (E*I) using scipy integrate.

SOLUTION, courtesy of gboffi:

```
#---------- DESCRIPTION

# cantilever beam with point load P at the free end
# original beam equation: y''(x) = M(x)/(E*I)
# moment equation: M(x) = -P*x
# x goes from the free end to the clamped end

# we have a second order diff eq: y''(x) = x
# we implement a new function:
#      h = y',
#      h' = y'' = M(x) = x

# we get a system of two ODE of first order
#      y' = h
#      h' = x

# we write the equations in vector form
#     Y' = F(x, Y(x)) = F(x,Y)

# we define a function that returns the original values

#----------- CODE

from __future__ import division
from numpy import linspace
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Exact solution, E*Iy = const, y1 = y', y0 = y, 
w = 10  #beam cross sec width (mm)
h = 10  #beam cross sec height (mm)
Iy = (w*h**3)/12   #cross sec moment of inertia (mm^4)
E = 200000   #steel elast modul (N/mm^2)
L = 100  #beam length(mm)
P = 100   #point load (N)

x = linspace(0, L, 51)

y1 = (-P/(2*E*Iy))*x**2+(P*L**2)/(2*E*Iy)
y0 = (-P/(6*E*Iy))*x**3+((P*L**2)/(2*E*Iy))*x-(2*P*L**3)/(6*E*Iy)

# Define the vector function for E=const for integration
def F(x,Y):
    #unpack the vector function
    y = Y[0]
    h = Y[1]
    #compute the derivatives
    dy_dx = h
    dh_dx = (-P/(E*Iy))*x
    #return the vector of derivatives values
    return [dy_dx, dh_dx]

# Numerical solution
s = solve_ivp(
    F, # Y[0]=y0, Y[1]=y1, dy0dx=y1, dy1dx=x
    [L, 0.0], # interval of integration (NB: reversed, because...)
    [0.0, 0.0], # initial conditions (at the 1st point of integ interval)
    t_eval=linspace(L, 0, 101) # where we want the solution to be known
    )

# Plotting
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)
ax1.plot(x, y0, label="Exact y")
ax2.plot(x, y1, label="Exact y'")
ax1.plot(s.t[::2], s.y[0][::2], label="Numeric y",  linestyle='', marker='.')
ax2.plot(s.t[::2], s.y[1][::2], label="Numeric y'", linestyle='', marker='.')
plt.show()
```

---

EXACT SOLUTION: exact solution is made by integrating the beam equation twice using definite integrals and use the boundary conditions to define the integral constants. Everything is explained in the wiki link above. Below is the code to plot the y''(x), y'(x) (slope) and y(x) (deflection). The diagram is turned around, the free end of the beam is at x = 0.

```
from __future__ import division  #to enable normal floating division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Beam parameters
w = 10  #beam cross sec width (mm)
h = 10  #beam cross sec height (mm)
I = (w*h**3)/12   #cross sec moment of inertia (mm^4)
I1 = (w*h**3)/12
E = 200000   #steel elast modul (N/mm^2)
L = 100  #beam length(mm)
F = 100   #force (N)

# Define equations
def d2y_dx2(x):
    return (-F*x)/(E*I)

def dy_dx(x):
    return (1/(E*I))*(-0.5*F*x**2 + 0.5*F*L**2)

def y(x):
    return (1/(E*I))*(-(1/6)*F*(x**3) + (1/2)*F*(L**2)*x - (1/3)*F*(L**3))

# Plot
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3)

a = 0
b = L
x = np.linspace(a,b,100)

ax1.plot(x, d2y_dx2(x))
ax2.plot(x, dy_dx(x))
ax3.plot(x, y(x))
plt.show()
```

[image]

APPROXIMATE SOLUTION (KIND OF): the code below was made by willcrack. The shape looks better than in the previous question but the values are still not ok.

```
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Beam parameters
L = 100
w = 10
h = 10
I = (w*h**3)/12
E = 200000
F = 100

# Integration parameters
a = 0.0
b = L

# Define the beam equation
def d2y_dx2(x,y=None):
    return (-F*x)/(E*I)

    
# Define the integration1 - slope
def slope(x):
    slope_res = np.zeros_like(x)
    for i,val in enumerate(x):
        y,err = integrate.quad(f,a,val)
        slope_res[i]=y
    return slope_res

# Define the integration1 - deflection
def defl(x):
    
    defl_res = np.zeros_like(x)
    for i,val in enumerate(x):
        y, err = integrate.dblquad(d2y_dx2,0,val, lambda x: 0, lambda x: val)
        defl_res[i]=y
    return defl_res

# Plot
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3)
t = np.linspace(a,b,100)
t1 = np.linspace(a,b,100)
ax1.plot(t, d2y_dx2(t))
ax2.plot(t, slope(t))
ax3.plot(t1, defl(t1))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are integrating a differential equation, your approach of computing in a loop the definite integrals is, let's say, sub-optimal.

The standard approach in Scipy is the use of [`scipy.integrate.solve_ivp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html?highlight=solve_ivp#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp), that uses a suitable integration method (by default, Runge-Kutta 45) to provide the solution in terms of a special object.

As usual in the field of numerical integration of ordinary differential equations, the method is limited to a system of 1st order differential equation, but your 2nd degree equation can be transformed to a system of 1st degree equations introducing an helper function

```
    Y" = M ⇒ {y' = h, h' = M}
```

While this sounds complicated, its implementation is quite simple

```
In [51]: #########################################################################
    ...: # L, EJ = 1.0
    ...: #########################################################################
    ...: # exact solution
    ...: from numpy import linspace
    ...: x = linspace(0, 1, 51)
    ...: y1, y0 = (x**2-1)/2, (x**3-3*x+2)/6
    ...: #########################################################################
    ...: # numerical solution
    ...: from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
    ...: s = solve_ivp(
    ...:     lambda x, Y: [Y[1], x], # Y[0]=y0, Y[1]=y1, dy0dx=y1, dy1dx=x
    ...:     [1.0, 0.0], # interval of integration (NB: reversed, because...)
    ...:     [0.0, 0.0], # initial conditions (at the 1st point of integ interval)
    ...:     t_eval=np.linspace(1, 0, 101) # where we want the solution to be known
    ...:     )
    ...: #########################################################################
    ...: # plotting
    ...: from matplotlib.pyplot import grid, legend, plot
    ...: plot(x, y0, label="Exact y")
    ...: plot(x, y1, label="Exact y'")
    ...: plot(s.t[::2], s.y[0][::2], label="Numeric y",  linestyle='', marker='.')
    ...: plot(s.t[::2], s.y[1][::2], label="Numeric y'", linestyle='', marker='.')
    ...: legend() ; grid() ;

In [52]:
```

[image]

---

---

The OP reported an issue understanding `solve_ivp(lambda x, Y: [Y[1], x], ...`.

We have a system of 1st order ODEs in normal form

```
y₁' = f₁(x, y₁(x), …, yₙ(x))
…   = …
yₙ' = f₁(x, y₁(x), …, yₙ(x))
```

that can be written, using capital letters to signify vector quantities

```
Y' = F(x, Y(x))
```

to solve the system of differential equations `solve_ipv` needs exactly this `F(x, Y)` function.

In place of the lambda expression one could write a function definition like the following, that is possibly more self explanatory

```
def F(x, Y):
    # unpack the vector of function values
    y = Y[0]
    h = Y[1]
    # compute the derivatives
    dy_over_dx = h
    dh_over_dx = x
    # return the vector of derivatives values
    return [dy_over_dx, dh_over_dx]

s = solve_ivp(F, …)
```

that in the answer was succinctly (too much succinctly?) was expressed as `lambda x,Y:[Y[1],x]` …

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you explain why the approach in the question is sub-optimal? Regarding your code, I'm having a really tough time (I'm still a novice in this) trying to understand how you implemented the differential equation in the solve_ivp(). What does [Y[1], x] mean?

Comment: Sub-optimal in the sense of the ratio _accuracy over computational effort_.  Have you read the documentation of [`solve_ivp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html), that I have linked in the answer? In short `Y[0]` is _y_ and `Y[1]` is _h_, and because the derivatives of our system are _dy/dx = h_ and _dh/dt = x_ the value returned by the lambda expression is a list `[Y[1], x]`.  Maybe it's better to explain this issue in the answer…

Comment: Yes I have checked it, but this is completely new to me. I will try this again tomorrow and post a longer explanation of huge holes in my understanding of the problem in an answer.

Comment: The documentation covers a lot of specialized issues and corner cases, I imagine that at first sight it could be disarranging. I have enhanced (oh well, I hope so…) my answer with an explanation of the lambda expression that I used in the body of the answer.

Comment: I tried over and over again to understand how you implemented this method, but I always just get lost. 1.: I suppose you simplified the equation in OP so that -F/E*I = 1 and y''=x? 2.: The system of ODE is then y' = h and h' = M. What is this M? 3.: In the second comment you wrote that x = dh/dt. Where did you then use the variable t? 4.: How is the input of the function F(x,Y) connected to the return?

Comment: I would really like to understand the method because my ultimate goal is to have a quick method to plot the deflection of the beam when I is not a constant and is a function of x, I = f(x).

Comment: ① In my code above there is this comment `# L, EJ = 1.0` ② `M` is the bending moment, that is `M(x) = x` ③ No, I wrote that `dh/dt=x` and unluckily I made a mistake because what I really meant was `dh/dx=x` (or, if you prefer, the derivative of the derivative equals the current (the current position) value of the bending moment) ④ the inputs of `F` are the current values of `x` and of the function and its derivative, the outputs are the values of the derivative and of the derivative of the derivative, aka the second derivative.

Comment: `def F(x, Y): return(Y[1], M(x)/E/J(x))`

Comment: If you want to take into account also other boundary conditions and/or statically undetermined systems, you want to know about `scipy.integrate.solve_bvp` (_ivp_ Initial Value Problem, _bvp_ Boundary Value Problem). Please let's stop here this discussion and ask different questions if you have other doubts.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation 2 comments above, this makes everything much much less cloudy. I will go through everything again and try to write my own code and also check out the .solve_bvp and post the update and mark your answer as answered. Thanks a lot, I really appreciate you taking your own time to explain some basics to me.

Comment: You're welcome.  It's always a pleasure to help someone that shows your genuine interest in the topic.